# FactoryGirl and after_create callback in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have two models `Board` and `Category` with relation has_many/belongs_to.

In `Board` I have `after_create` callback creating default Category for it.
So when I create Board, it automatically creates default Category for it.

```
after_create do 
  categories.create(name: "All Links", description: nil)
end
```

Now I create basic :board factory:

```
factory :board do
  name {Faker::Lorem.sentence(rand(5)+1)}
  description {Faker::Lorem.paragraph(rand(5))}
end
```

I have Board instance method: root_category which returns this default Category.

My question is, how can I create :category factory based on this :board.root factory, and #root_category method? Something like:

```
factory :category do
  1. board = FactoryGirl.create(:board)
  2. returns board.root_category as a factory output.
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be solved directly but there are more concerns than solution.

To answer exactly your question, you don't need a "category" factory to create root category for a board. The callback will be executed at model level, no need interfering of FactoryGirl.

#### Some more concerns

1. It's not good practice to use callbacks on external models/classes. Category is outside of Board, so Board should not call Category in it's callbacks which is supposed a private space. Instead, a better approach is to add root category to a board in BoardsController's #create
2. You may need to reconsider your modelling. In common sense a model and its category would be better in many to many relationship. Suppose, in your case, a board has category "Coding", then "Coding" category can no longer be used on other board in your modelling!